# Creating nested tablix in rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I believe there will be a relatively simple solution for this, however I am yet to find it.

I am creating a simple rdlc report in a visual studio 2012 windows forms application, adding a dataset and dragging and dropping these fields into my tablix. All this worked fine, however I now want to add a tablix inside one of my row fields. I want it to look like the image below, and I want to do it fairly painlessly through the designer.[image]

Above is an exmaple of the table I am trying to create, with all contained fields in the same row of the same dataset with the Date, Start, and End fields being the problem area's I cannot create.

I have tried to create these, however I get the error

The tablix ‘Tablix1’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.

After this I deleted some groups, and it compiled, however it then only showed the first line of data from the datatset.

I also wondered whether there may be a way to move the tablix headers from rows to columns, so the headers go down the left instead of across the top, but I cannot seem to find a way to do this either.

I am fairly new to this so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Tablix opérate strictly on same dataset, join tables.

Refer to a good explanation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207033.aspx

Comment: As it stands this answer is pretty much just a link. Can you edit to add some more explanation or an example?

Comment: Link doesn't have answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead of creating the nested table which will have alignment issues and improper final look, it is better to use the Rows of the table itself by adjusting the border color of each cell.

I had tried it and final outcome was as expected, it looked like I have used nested table.

For example, I want the design as per
[ExampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pvDq.png)

To achieve this:

1. I had dragged and dropped table control from toolbox and added table headers.
2. Added 7 rows and 11 columns.
3. After 'h5', I had merged 4 columns and named it as 'h6' and 's1', which look like nested table.
4. Click on F4, you can view the properties of the table.
5. Click on each cell (Ctrl + cells to select and format a group of cells) and change the border color by expanding the 'border color' property and assigning color to left, right, top or bottom as required.
6. Only for the 4 columns under 'h6' provide the border color for entire cell.